# NestJS custom decorator returns undefined

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Good morning,

I'm trying to create a custom decorator:
`user.decorator.ts`

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;

    return data ? user && user[data] : user;
  },
);
```

`user.entity.ts`

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BeforeInsert } from "typeorm";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { UserRO } from "./user.dto";

@Entity("user")
export class UserEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 50,
        unique: true,
    })
    username: string;

    @Column('text')
    password: string;

    @Column('text')
    role: string;

    (...)
}
```

And finally, `user.controller.ts` (only the useful part):

```
(...)
    @Post('login')
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
    login(@Body() data: UserDTO,  @User('role') role: string) {
        console.log(`hello ${role}`);
        return this.userService.login(data);
(...)
    }
```

My problem: console.log(...) returns me `hello undefined`, when the expected response should be `hello admin` (as admin is the role of the user in the database)

EDIT: I also tried to `console.log(user)` in my decorator and it is undefined too.

EDIT2: My HttpErrorFilter also says: `Cannot read property 'role' of undefined`

I followed closely the documentation and I can't figure out where the problem is (https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also been confused about this. I upgraded to NestJS 7, and following the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide) was trying to update my user decorator.

The part I could not get working is `const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();`.  For some reason `getRequest()` was returning undefined.

What worked for me is:

```typescript
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    return ctx.getArgByIndex(2).req.user;
  }
);
```

The [execution context](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context) docs advise against `getArgByIndex()`, so I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong.  Interested in what the other answers and comments will say.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In `user.decorator.ts`:

Change `const user = request.user;` with `const user = request.body;`

According to nestjs's doc, it should be `.user` but when I looked deeper into the request, I noticed there were no 'user' but a 'body' with all in the informations. (https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)

Can't tell if I messed up earlier or if the doc is just outdated.

Problem solved whatsoever !

EDIT: 2nd solution:

I forgot to use `@UseGuards(new AuthGuard())` on top, and the `request.user` is created with the AuthGuard..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting mad with this empty/undefined request. Because that info in documentation ([custom-decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)) was not working for me. I'm using graphql + typescript. Then the solution that did the magic was this:

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        return ctx.getContext().req.user;
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same decorator for HTTP(REST) and graphql

```
if (ctx.getType() == 'http') {
  return ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
} else {
  const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(ctx);
  return gqlContext.getContext().user;
}
```