# how to get user data with req.user on decorator in nest js

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I created the authentication ( jwt ) and the process is done properly.

I can access the user's information using the following code, but I can't get the user's information using the decorator!

controller :

```
@Post('/me/info')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  myInfo(
    @GetUser() user,
    @Req() req,
  ) {
    console.log(user); // undefined 
    console.log(req.user); // get user data object
  }
```

my decorator is:

```
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './user.entity';

export const GetUser = createParamDecorator((data, req): User => {
  return req.user;
});
```

what is my code problem ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is in `createParamDecorator`.

An excerpt from the [official manual on custom decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators):

```ts
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was working with Typescript and graphql so the above solution didn't work for me. Perhaps you should see this solution.

[NestJS custom decorator returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753807/nestjs-custom-decorator-returns-undefined/62650047#62650047)